# Restriction on specific content types for admin content page filter

Tags: 8, views

I need help with removing a content type from admin/content page's content type filter in D8.

Let's say I have content type1, content type2 and content type3.

I want to have an exposed filter in admin/content page for content type1 and content type3.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just go to the /admin/structure/views/view/content and edit the 
Content: Content type (exposed) filter in the "Filter Criteria Tab" of your view.

Then just select  your type1 and type 2.

[image]

Comment: I don't think you understand my question. I want to list only content type1 and 3. Simply saying, I'd like to remove content type 2 from the exposed filter.

Comment: Yep, this is what i understand! Maybe i should add that you have to select 'limit to selected items' on the bottom of that views filter settings page, i'll update my screenshot

Comment: Oh yeah I didn't see that at the bottom. It works now. Thank you @Nikko